# How do I get a list of ssid from browser?

Tags: browser, network-programming

I need to build a web based application that can list available ssid in the area.

From my understanding, these probably can do what i want

- Java applet
- Adobe Flash

However, Im not sure whether these can do or not

- HTML5/JavaScript
- Java Web Start

I'm a .NET developer and I'm not familiar with these web technologies.
Are there any other method to get a list of SSID that i have not mentioned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to list available SSID's with HTML5, Javascript, or any other strictly web-based technology.  That's a very low-level task and won't be natively possible in any browser for security reasons.  That being said, you may be able to draw on some technology like Java Applets, ActiveX, or even Silverlight 5 if I remember correctly.  I don't know your project requirements, but you're better off creating a native application for this type of feature.  If this application is being used by/sold to the general public, you're setting yourself up for a lot of headache by going with Applets/ActiveX/etc.

Comment: It's worth noting these headache technologies are dying fast, and in some browsers already dead.

Comment: Absolutely @AlexanderO'Mara.  The company I work for now is having to redesign some portions of our web application to migrate away from ActiveX controls and Silverlight.

Comment: How about ClickOnce for .Net? Is it a comparable to Java Applet? My enterprise policy allows applet for security reasons(binary signed certificated).